# Residue theorem: understood it intuitively but cannot prove mathematically

Tags: complex-analysis

In my opinion, residue theorem’s underlying principle is quite beautiful: one decomposes a contour integral into infinitely many small circular contour integrals around every point, and most of them are zero, except a few that encircle singularities. Those are called residues, and add them up. This is basically how residue theorem works.

However, when I try to prove it by Green’s theorem, I face some difficulties. ($f=u+iv$)

$$\oint_C f(z)dz=\oint(u+iv)dx+i(u+iv)dy=\iint_D \frac{\partial (u+iv)}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial (u+iv)}{\partial y}dxdy$$

I don’t see how can this be transformed into a sum of residues/circular contour integrals around singularities.

Can you please show how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given a region $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ with boundary cycle $\partial\Omega$ and a function $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb C}$ which is analytic apart from finitely many isolated singularities at the points $a_j\in\Omega$ $(1\leq j\leq m)$. The trick now is to draw tiny discs $B_j$ of radius $\epsilon>0$ centered at these points. Then we consider the punched domain $\Omega':=\Omega\setminus\bigcup_{j=1}^m B_j$ with boundary cycle
$$\partial\Omega'=\partial\Omega-\sum_{j=1}^m \partial B_j\ .$$
Note  the minus signs here! The function $f$ is analytic in $\Omega'$; therefore we may apply Green's, resp., Cauchy's,  theorem to $f$ and $\Omega'$. It follows that $\int_{\partial\Omega'}f(z)\>dz=0$, so that 
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}f(z)\>dz=\sum_{j=1}^m\int_{\partial B_j}f(z)\>dz\ .$$
Here the LHS is independent of $\epsilon$. It follows that
$$\int_{\partial\Omega}f(z)\>dz=\sum_{j=1}^m\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\partial B_j}f(z)\>dz=2\pi i \sum_{j=1}^m{\rm res}(f, a_j)\ ,$$
by definition of the residue.

Comment: This is brilliant. Just one thing: how can I derive with details and rigor that $$\int_{\partial\Omega+\partial B}=\int_{\partial\Omega}+\int_{\partial B}$$ to ‘convince’ a starter in complex analysis? (I know this is almost trivial to you.)

Comment: Also, to my surprise, I cannot google a similar proof. Indeed, a formal proof of residue theorem is quite rare on the internet.

Comment: Already $\partial\Omega$ might consist of several disjoint closed curves. If you accept the  notion of boundary cycle as defined in your community, as well as the notion of integral over a chain (formal sum of smooth curves) then there is no problem with $\partial\Omega'=\partial\Omega-\sum_j\partial B_j$.